# When to delete useMemo cached values

Tags: reactjs

While using useMemo, I was wondering at what point does useMemo delete the values it has cached? If the values have not changed, at what point are the values cached in useMemo deleted from memory?

I don't think the cache value stored by useMemo is deleted from memory at the time of unmount, could you answer that question?

Comment: Check out the 3rd point in [useMemo Caveats](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo#caveats)

Comment: from the link posted by @vighnesh153

"React will not throw away the cached value unless there is a specific reason to do that"

Comment: It will be garbage collected when no references exist anymore. And we can't really be sure when GC will happen. Not sure if that's really what you meant by your question though.

Answer (score 0):

The React docs state

> React will not throw away the cached value unless there is a specific reason to do that

And it goes on to give examples of use cases where the cached value is deleted and they all seem to be dev-mode related.

Nowhere does it mention purging the cache when the component unmounts.

However, my intuition is that the cached value is saved within the scope of the component. So that when the component unmounts (gets removed from heap memory) the cached value eventually gets garbage collected, thereby effectively wiping the cache when the component unmounts